# Longest path in directed acyclic graph in jgrapht library

Tags: java, graph, shortest-path, jgrapht, longest-path

I want to find the longest path in directed (acyclic) graph. Let's say that I know starting node - sink. The path should begin from this point. 
I was thinking that I can set weights of edges to -1. There is many methods of finding all shortest path but you have to pass ending point. Is it possible to get the shortest path (no matter the end node)?

```
DirectedAcyclicGraph graph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
graph.addVertex(1);
graph.addVertex(2);
graph.addVertex(3);
graph.addVertex(4);
graph.addVertex(5);
graph.addVertex(6);
graph.addVertex(7);
graph.addVertex(8);
try {
    graph.addDagEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addDagEdge(2, 3);
    graph.addDagEdge(3, 4);
    graph.addDagEdge(5, 6);
graph.addDagEdge(2, 7);
graph.addDagEdge(7, 8);
} catch(Exception e) {

}
//????????????????
```

Let's say that I'd like to find longest path for node nr 1 (sink). So this algoritm shoud give me 1-2-3-4-5-6.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to a similar question to calculate parallel build groupings in Jenkins from a DAG of Git repos.  To solve it, I applied the algorithm described [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths).  The code below is written in Groovy, so you'll have to convert to Java.  The result is a Map of vertices to their respective max depths.  From that you can get the single largest value.  If instead you want to know the max depth from a specific vertex in the graph, you can first prune the graph into a subgraph rooted by your desired source vertex and then run the method below on the subgraph.

```
def calcDepths(g) {    

    Map<String, Integer> vertexToDepthMap = new HashMap<>()

    Iterator<String> iterator = new TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge>(g)
    iterator.each { v ->

        Set<String> predecessors = Graphs.predecessorListOf(g, v).toSet()
        Integer maxPredecessorDepth = -1
        predecessors.each { predecessor ->

            maxPredecessorDepth = Math.max(maxPredecessorDepth, vertexToDepthMap.get(predecessor))
        }

        vertexToDepthMap.put(v, maxPredecessorDepth + 1)
    }

    return vertexToDepthMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AllDirectedPaths](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/index.html?org/jgrapht/alg/shortestpath/AllDirectedPaths.html) algorithm to resolve all paths, sort the results by path length in reverse order and get the first:

```
    AllDirectedPaths<String, DefaultEdge> paths = new AllDirectedPaths<String, DefaultEdge>(graph);
    GraphPath<String, DefaultEdge> longestPath = paths.getAllPaths(source, target, true, null)
        .stream()
        .sorted((GraphPath<String, DefaultEdge> path1, GraphPath<String, DefaultEdge> path2)-> new Integer(path2.getLength()).compareTo(path1.getLength()))
        .findFirst().get();
    System.out.println(longestPath.getLength() +  " " + longestPath);
```

Comment: This triggers me how inefficient it would be for large graphs ...

Comment: Yes, this solution can only be applied to short depth graphs.